# ROC for binary classification SVM

Tags: r, svm, roc

I'm trying to compute the ROC and AUROC of a binary svm classification.
I already looked up a code in the internet and it's working:

```
Prediction_RBF<- as.numeric(prediction_RBF)

testset$Überdurchschnittlicher_Verkaufspreis_scaled <- as.numeric(testset$Überdurchschnittlicher_Verkaufspreis_scaled)

ROC_RBF <- roc(testset$Überdurchschnittlicher_Verkaufspreis_scaled, Prediction_RBF)

ROC_RBF
```

The values entered had to be numeric, so I transorfmed the prediction vector (I have used the predict() function by libsvm) into a numeric one.
I`m not sure if I'm allowed to do it like this and what's the meaning of the new vector. Is it the distance from the hyperplane or the probability?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Kind regards,

Anna